# Keycloak: After changing roles with admin API, I can't access to administration anymore

Tags: keycloak

Keycloak 15.0.2

I made a script that syncs external roles into Keycloak. I used the admin API `POST /{realm}/roles` for adding a role, and `DELETE /{realm}/roles/{role-name}` for removing a role. Since I performed the sync, I cant go anymore into the administration area over the browser.
The login screen appears, but after I login, the page becomes white, with following console error:

```
GET https://localhost/auth/admin/master/console/whoami 500 (Internal Server Error)    app.js:33
Uncaught TypeError: error is not a function                                           app.js:28 
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange (app.js:28)
```

and following keycloak error log

```
keycloak_app | 13:05:57,156 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-7) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
keycloak_app |  at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.entities.CachedRealm.<init>(CachedRealm.java:266)
keycloak_app |  at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@15.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealm(RealmCacheSession.java:414)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
keycloak_app |  at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@15.0.2//org.keycloak.utils.ClosingStream.forEach(ClosingStream.java:128)
keycloak_app |  at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@15.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminConsole.addMasterRealmAccess(AdminConsole.java:258)
keycloak_app |  at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@15.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminConsole.whoAmI(AdminConsole.java:237)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
keycloak_app |  at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
keycloak_app |  at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@15.0.2//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
keycloak_app |  at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@15.0.2//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@15.0.2//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
keycloak_app |  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
keycloak_app |  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
keycloak_app |  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
keycloak_app |  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
keycloak_app |  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
keycloak_app |  at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
keycloak_app |  at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
keycloak_app |  at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
keycloak_app |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
keycloak_app |
```

I added roles only with the `name` attribute. Now any call to the admin API gives an error 500, so i cant even add new roles with other attributes, for trying to add missing attributes.

Any ideas on how to get access again to the admin area? Should I fix the roles hardly in the DB, if yes, how can I access the data, and what should be changed?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to check the roles you have in the database for this user (admin user)? Should be (at least in my case where it works):

"realm-management"
"manage-users",
"view-clients",
"create-client",
"impersonation",
"manage-authorization",
"manage-clients",
"manage-events",
"manage-identity-providers",
"manage-realm",
"realm-admin",